# Moodle 2.2.3 TinyMCE loads slowly

Tags: performance, tinymce, loading, moodle

In Moodle 2.2.3, after 10-12 seconds TinyMCE (TinyMCE HTML editor; editor_tinymce; Standard;    2012030300) buttons will show up (loads very slowly). Where problem lies? Can't figure out how to speed up TinyMCE HTML editor loading time.

I have Moodle 2.2.3+ (Build: 20120519).

Comment: we need some more information here (system, browser, browser addOns, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. The cause, why it was slow, was because it was in estonian. I had to change whole user language into english and it fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem: on my project tinymce loaded about 10 seconds. Solution to speed it up was to disable plugins, which I don't need.

For example:
at default config plugins option was:

```
 plugins: "visualblocks,visualchars,pagebreak,layer,table,save,jbimages,link,emoticons,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,template",
```

After remove unused plugins it was:

```
plugins: "jbimages,link",
```

and editor loading became 2 seconds.

P.S. jbimages is a plugin to upload images.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your caching. The tinyMCE JS files ought to be kept by the browser and recycled, but sometimes this doesn't happen. Use Firebug or Chrome developer tools to see if they are being loaded from cache or from the server. If from the server, you may need to tweak your web server settings so that JS files have an expires header.